# $nin operator doesn't work correctly

Tags: mongodb

When I use this method, I get all documents from _User collection. (as expected)

```
db.getCollection("_User").find({ "_id" : { $nin: [] }})
```

However, when I add at least one string to $nin array:

```
db.getCollection("_User").find({ "_id" : { $nin: ["7HpHbmF5iu","ga61t3afsa"] }})
```

I get empty results. (expected - to get all documents without the ones with ids 7HpHbmF5iu and ga61t3afsa)

MongoDB version 3.2.6

These are two documents I want to filter from all:

```
{ "_id" : "7HpHbmF5iu", "expiration_date" : ISODate("2015-12-28T08:51:21.252Z"), "_created_at" : ISODate("2015-10-29T08:51:23.302Z"), "_updated_at" : ISODate("2016-03-10T17:37:45.262Z"), "gender" : "female", "firstName" : "Toma", "verification" : "verified", "birthdayDate" : ISODate("1995-02-15T00:00:00Z") }

{ "_id" : "ga61t3afsa", "expiration_date" : ISODate("2015-12-27T07:54:21.235Z"), "_created_at" : ISODate("2015-10-28T07:11:22.102Z"), "_updated_at" : ISODate("2016-03-11T16:11:10.100Z"), "gender" : "female", "firstName" : "Goda", "verification" : "verified", "birthdayDate" : ISODate("1992-09-13T00:00:00Z") }
```

Comment: Please add the respective documents.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Added

Comment: Weird, that query looks fine and works when I try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an error in Azure DocumentDB with Mongo, however I've chosen not to use their services, so I don't know if they've already fixed it.